# Postman adding values to request json

Tags: postman, postman-pre-request-script

Hi I am hoping this is a simple question.

In my `pre-request-script` I am getting a JSON object back from a GET.

This JSON object has 10 fields.  I would like to add 2 more.

I tried `myJson.add` and `myJson.push` but those don't work.  How would I accomplish this task?  I am then taking that `myJson` and adding it to a push request in the test.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Provide how your JSON is structured and what code you currently have in your pre-request script, to make it easier for folks to help you out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**With the lack of data in the description, I'm providing a very general answer**

Assuming `myJson` contains your JSON string, first parse it to convert the JSON data to an object as follows:

```
let jsonObj = JSON.parse(myJson);
```

Once done, now you can add/remove/update the data - depending on the structure of your JSON.

For example, assuming your data is an array:

```
[ 
    {
       "data": "value"
    },
    {
       "data": "value2"
    }
]
```

You can add another element by using:

```
jsonObj.push({"data": "value3"});
```

Once you are done updating the data, convert it back to string as follows:

```
myJson = JSON.stringify(jsonObj);
```

You can now store this in an environment variable etc for use in the Postman request.

*Reference*: https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/variables/